# Diferential equations's linear approximation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

Take for example the well known

$$ \ddot{\phi} + \frac{g}{l} \sin{\phi} = 0.$$

Usually, in a physics course they might say that by Taylor's Theorem we can write, for small angles:

$$\ddot{\phi} + \frac{g}{l} \phi = 0 $$

However, in my ODE's course, I've been thaught that if we want to make a linear approximation of

$$\dot{\mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{F}( \mathbf{X},t)$$

arround an equilibrium point $P$, we have to use the Hartman - Grobman's Theorem (or a simplyfied version of it).

I agree that computing the jacobian matrix of $\mathbf{F}$ at $P$, $A$, will be the same as doing a first order Taylor in this case. But, there might be cases where the linear term is zero (the determinant of the $A$ is zero) and the theorem does not apply. If we think we are doing a Taylor approximation, we might be tempted to do a second (or higher) order approximation and, since it's not explicited in the theorem, might not always be true.

The question is: are we doing a Taylor approximation (it can be deduced from Taylor's Theorem / i.e. higher order approximations are allowed) or the correct way of approximating ODEs is the second one but we say we are doing "Taylor's approximations" because it's essentially the same thing for linear terms?

Comment: There is no such thing as permission, in math or elsewhere. You are allowed to do whatever you want, as long as you’re willing to handle the consequences. You can do a linear approximation, and it will have some accuracy that you have to live with; that’s all.

Comment: "Usually, in Physics courses", it's later solved without the linear/Taylor approximation. The answer is somehow an elliptic function which can be expanded to recover the linear approximation.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, I am aware of that. When I say allowed I mean "mathematically correct". Taylor's Theorem gives an approximation for a function, that does not necesarily means that approximating each coordinate of $\mathbf{F}({\mathbf{X},t)$ with a Taylor expansion gives an approximative solution. That's why Hardman - Grobman's Theorem exist, isn't it?

Comment: @Felix Marin, Perhaps I should have written "101 physics courses". Anyways, my question isn't about that particular ODE or phyisics courses, it's about the procedure. I apologise if it's not clear enought.

Comment: So is your question whether the Hartman-Grobman theorem applies here? Here the Jacobian is a $1 \times 1$ matrix and its only eigenvalue is $\frac{g}{\ell}$ whose real part is not equal to zero. So it's fine, right?

Comment: My question is why there is a Hartman's Theorem if we already knew how to do it with Taylor. IMO, using Taylor as I did in the example, is a priori not correct, since Taylor's Theorem says how to approximate a function around a point, it doesn't says that approximating the $\mathbf{F}$ implies that we are approximating  $\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan no Hartman-Grobman doesn't apply directly here, because this is a second order ODE. Even if we re-write this as an equivalent system of first-order ODEs: $(\phi,\psi)' = f(\phi,\psi) = (\psi, -\omega^2 \sin \phi)$, where $\omega = \sqrt{g/l}$ then the derivative at the equilibrium point $Df_{(0,0)}$ has eigenvalues $\pm i \omega$, both of which have real-part zero (which is of course why the linearized system has periodic solutions $A\sin(\omega t)+ B\cos (\omega t)$). THerefore even after the equivalent rewriting, the hypotheses of Hartman-Grobman aren't satisfied.

Comment: my bad I said "the equilibrium point", when I should have said "an equilibrium point"

Comment: I'll update with a particular case one of this days. This example has the only purpose of illustrating what I meant by "using Taylor" for approximating an ODE.